# Moving the program to the stack [Assembly 80x86]

Tags: assembly, stack

Hello and thanks in advance!

I'm working on an assembly project and I need to move the code of my program to the stack and continue the flow of the program from there.

This means the program will start in the code segment and move to the stack segment while running itself. There it will perform a task given to it (for now, let it loop there indefinetly).

I've tried a few ideas:

```
PUSH word [cs:jump]
MOV cx, sp
PUSH SS
PUSH SP
MOV BP, SP
ADD word [word BP], 2
JMP FAR [BP]
jump:
JMP cx
```

this compiles, but does not work.

The assembly language is Intel's 16-bit assembly for 80x86.
The assembler is nasm.

Thanks for all the helpers.

Comment: *Need* to move the program to the stack?  That's a pretty unusual need. It is likely your problem can be solved some other way. [You are also likely to run into trouble with on modern processors: the stack area is usually marked as "not executable" so even if you move your program there, you actually might not be able to execute it.  You seem to be working with a pure x86, so execute protection may not apply].

Comment: I've seen an example program that can do this on assembly 80x86, the problem is that it was written for tasm, not nasm. I can't seem to "convert" it properly.

Comment: I found the program made for tasm:




    P286N
    IDEAL
    DOSSEG
    MODEL small
    STACK 100H
    
    CODESEG
    start:
    push [word cs:exit + 4]
    push [word cs:exit + 2]
    push [word cs:exit]
    push ss
    push sp
    mov bp, sp
    add [word bp], 2
    jmp[dword bp]
    exit:
    mov ah, 4CH
    mov al, 0
    int 21H
    END start

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're compiling the code with the default bin output format to produce a .COM file. If so, you need to be aware that .COM files load at an offset of 100h in memory. You need to make the assembler aware of this by adding an ORG directive at the start of the code.

```
ORG 100h
```

Once you've done that, your code should work as expected. Without the ORG directive, the assembler assumes a start address of 0, so the *jump* memory reference would be off by 100h bytes.

For more information, see the [NASM documentation](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc8.html#section-8.2.1).